# What does ":=" mean in Pseudocode?

Tags: syntax, pseudocode, colon-equals

Really basic syntax question in pseudocode. What does `:=` mean in Pseudocode?
Example

```
a := 1
```

Comment: I just want to know what ":=" operator does and how it is different from just "="

Comment: What is it translating *from*?

Comment: @Aneem *Try using it*. What happens? It is not valid in Python, but some *other* languages use `:=` for the assignment operator.

Comment: That's a Pascal assignment. Did you get the wrong language. Show some more code.

Comment: sorry! it's not python, it was using coding from this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Comment: Can we delete this post? It is misleading, once again, very sorry.

Comment: Instead of deleting, why not just change your question to be about pseudocode instead of Python? I will remove my downvote, for one

Comment: It's that well known language, **pseudocode**

Comment: Haha @DavidHeffernan, what I mean is that pseudocode does have a StackOverflow tag.

Comment: Voting to close as i doubt this question will have value to anyone in the future.  I was going to remove the Python tag, except it specifically says Python on the title.

Comment: See - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/101716/in-pseudo-code-what-does-mean

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Pseudocode examples on Wikipedia usually use `:=` as the assignment operator, like Pascal does (I haven't found any counterexamples yet).

You can't use it in Python directly as it would be a `SyntaxError`:

```
>>> a := 1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a := 1
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Use

```
a = 1
```

instead.

Comment: The question could get deleted though..... You might lose the rep but I think you'll keep the badge!  ;-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I think if that happens I do get to keep the badge, but I don't get another one when my next answer reaches 10 upvotes...

Comment: I hate to star negatively-voted questions, but I just had to do this after seeing your answer.

Comment: Wow, we even have a Programmers counterpart: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/101716/in-pseudo-code-what-does-mean

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: You should look through the revision history of the question to see what it started out as. In its current state it isn't such a bad question any more IMO, but it was quite funny at the start.

Answer (score 11):

In pseudo code `:= means assignment` whereas `= means equality`

`a:=1 in pseudo code means a=1 in most languages` while, a=1 is generally used for conditional checking in pseudo code i.e. `if(a=1) in pseudocode means if (a==1) in most languages`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about translating from another language, the := operator is used in pascal like languages for assigning variables.

In python the equivalent would just be =.

Pascal:

```
a := 1
```

Python:

```
a = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Pascal:

```
a := 1
```

Python:

```
a = 1
```

:)